# Theano function that can take input arrays of different shapes in python

Tags: python, function, input, theano

In theano, I want to make a function that can take several different inputs, such as both matrices and vectors.

Normally I would do something like this:

```
import theano
import numpy


x = theano.tensor.matrix(dtype=theano.config.floatX)
y = 3*x
f = theano.function([x],y)
```

However, then when I enter a vector instead of a matrix, for example:

```
f(numpy.array([1,2,3]))
```

Then I get an error of dimension mismatch: 'Wrong number of dimensions: expected 2, got 1 with shape (3,).'

Is there any way to define a more general input symbol in theano that can take matrices but also different shaped arrays such as vectors or 3-dimensional arrays and still works?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of dimensions must be fixed at the time the Theano function is compiled. Part of the compilation process is to select operation variants that depend on the number of dimensions.

You could always compile the function for a high-dimensional tensor and just stack your inputs such that they have the required shape.

So

```
x = theano.tensor.tensor3()
y = 3*x
f = theano.function([x],y)
```

will accept and of these

```
f(numpy.array([[[1,2]]]))  # (1,1,3) vector wrapped as a tensor3
f(numpy.array([[[1,2],[3,4]]]))  # (1,2,2) matrix wrapped as a tensor3
f(numpy.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]))  # (2,2,2) tensor3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's just the answer I need, so I can stop spending my time on searching for something that cannot be done ;)